# How do I specify a criteria that compares dates in Excel's SUMIFS function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010, which includes the [SUMIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) function. My spreadsheet is in this format:

```
    A          B            C
  Date       Amount      Category
01/01/2013   $20.00      CatA
01/12/2013   $35.67      CatB
02/04/2013   $16.98      CatA
```

etc. In another part of the spreadsheet, I have these cells:

```
       X            Y
1               CatA_header
2    Jan-13     formula...
3    Feb-13 
4    Mar-13
```

I'd like to place a formula in the cell specified by `formula...` (in cell Y2) that sums column B for the given category and the given year/month combination. I thought `SUMIFS` was right for the task, so I tried this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, AND(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(X2), YEAR(A:A)=YEAR(X2)), C:C, "="&Y1)
```

However, this returns 0, even though it should return 20 in my contrived example. How can I use the `SUMIFS` function to perform this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your row numbers seem to be off by 1, e.g., `Y0`. Also, you can't filter the criteria range like that, I don't think. Here's a SUMPRODUCT that works on rows 2 to 10:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$10)*(MONTH($A$2:$A$10)=MONTH(X2))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$10)=YEAR(X2))*($C$2:$C$10= Y$1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The row numbers were just a notation mistake when I wrote the question, but your solution works great.

Comment: @Doug you're genius man) your answers make me feel ugly and learn eagerly! my +1.